# Is $k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$ a local ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I noticed that a system of parameters is defined in local rings and some books say that $\{x^4,y^4\}$ is a system of parameters for $R=k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$. Is $R$ a local ring or we use it refers to $R_{\mathfrak m}$? (Here $\mathfrak m=(x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R$ is a graded $k$-algebra and for such algebras we can talk about *homogeneous systems of parameters* which are in fact homogeneous elements generating an ideal whose radical is the maximal irrelevant ideal $\mathfrak m$.
It's a matter of fact that a homogeneous system of parameters is a system of parameters in $R_m$.
Now you can chose between the two cases which one want to consider.

**Edit.** It seems that you want to be convinced that $R$ is not local. For this let $\mathfrak p=(x^4,x^3y,xy^3)$ be a prime ideal of $R$, and add to this ideal another generator different from $y^4$, e.g. $y^4+1$. The ideal $\mathfrak n=(x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4+1)$ is maximal. (To have all these as a clear as possible I suggest you to look at the isomorphism proved in [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757832/are-r-ka-b-c-d-ad-bc-a2c-b3-bd2-c3-ac2-b2d-and-kx4-x3y-xy3-y).)

Comment: Thanks, it seems as R is not a local ring, what does other maximal ideals look like?

Comment: @Strongart Besides the impossible task to determine *all* the maximal ideals of this ring, the philosophy is that they don't count! For a graded k-algebra the irrelevant maximal ideal says everything we want to know.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer.